# Some characters of the Consola font are rendered twice their height

Tags: visual-studio, fonts, consolas

Does anyone know why is it that the ASCII characters ░, ▒ and ▓ are rendered with twice their supposed height (under some applications)?

Microsoft Word appears to render them correctly but Visual Studio, for example, renders them incorrectly.
See screenshot here: [Screenshot 1](http://xfx.net/consolas_rendering_issue/ss02.png)

Graphics.DrawString appears to have a similar problem: [Screenshot 2](http://xfx.net/consolas_rendering_issue/ss01.png)

Comment: Use connect.microsoft.com to report problems like this.

Comment: Thank you @HansPassant, I though there might be some obvious explanation that I may have overlooked.

Comment: Here's a link to the report at [connect.microsoft.com](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/776595/some-consola-font-characters-are-rendered-with-twice-their-height)